# How to remove all folders except for one specific folder in Python 3

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to write a script that deletes all useless folders except one. I searched in many forums for a solution, but nothing works.

I want to delete everything in `./Desktop/D`, and the folder I want to keep is `./Desktop/D/ksg`.

This is what I came up with, but it only deletes everything in `/D`. Thanks for every help.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

def ordnerdelete(pfad):
    for path in Path(pfad).rglob("ksg"):
        if (pfad != path):
            for f in os.listdir("./Desktop/D/./."):
                os.remove(os.path.join("./Desktop/D/./.", f))
            os.rmdir(pfad)
    print(pfad, "gelöscht")


programm = "./Desktop/D/."

ordnerdelete(programm)
```

Comment: "Nothing works" is not a valid error description - what happens when you try your code? You are using relative pathing (`"./Desktop/D/."` is based on the current folder)  - did you `print` the combined pathes your code produces? do they make sense?

Comment: I made that code out of another one for the same project that worked on deleting the folders and files I wanted. I get a premission error for "./Desktop/D/./.\\ksg and line 8, 15 are smh wrong

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself if somebody needs it for his project

```
import os 
import shutil
from pathlib import Path 


pfad = Path("./Desktop/D/.")
projekt = "ksg"
liste = os.listdir(pfad)

for f in liste:
    if f != projekt:  
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(pfad, f))
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error: %s : %s" % (f, e.strerror))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).